# String Deduplication with Flatbuffers in Java

Tags: java, flatbuffers

The [Cpp API](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/classflatbuffers_1_1_flat_buffer_builder.html#ab478a645216d2d613fc7b7c29b0ff9d1) references a `CreateSharedString` function to perform String deduplication. It seems there is also a specific `shared` attribute in the flatbuffers DSL.

Unfortunately, I cannot find an equivalent in the Java API nor any documentation about the `shared` attribute.

Is it possible to create shared strings with the Java API? if yes, how to do?

Should I maintain a map of Strings and their offset for calls to FlatBufferBuilder#createString and perform a check against this map, or is flatbuffers providing a better mean in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this yourself, if need be. If you serialize an offset you get from `createString` in 2 or more places, you are using sharing. Using your own map to see if you have already serialized a string and reusing its offset is fine.

Sadly of course this makes the serialization process slower (and use more memory), but this may be worth it if you have a lot of repeating strings.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I ended up with a custom map to reuse offsets.